# c# File in xml format not opening in xml viewer

Tags: c#, xml, console

Created a .xml file in C# console program using StreamWriter without using any xml write library functions). However, it does not show data in XML viewer - shows fine if opened as a text file.
I tried, like I saw somewhere on this site, the following -

```
FileStream fStream = new FileStream (@"c:\new.xml", FileMode.Create)

StreamWriter fWrite = new StreamWriter(fStream, Encoding.UTF8);

fwrite.WriteLine (myLine);
```

where the first myLine was

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Is there a way to make this open like an xml file without having to use the xml lib functions?

Here's some more info - 
Contents of the file I wrote, as it opens in Notepad :
(OK, the contents are like below, but formatting isn't - the CTRL K that I was instructed to do here did the formatting!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OutermostTag>
      <RepetitiveInnerTag Action="AddSomething">
            <ID1>12345<ID1>
            <Level1>Leveldata1<Level1>
            <DisplayName>Name to Display<DisplayName>
            <Description>Describe it all here<Description>
            <SortOrder>ASC<SortOrder>
            <ID2>C3<ID2>
            <Level2>Data<Level2>
      </RepetitiveInnerTag>
</OutermostTag>
```

While opened as xml only the first inner tag (viz.,) data is displayed, space-demited as follows:

```
12345 Leveldata1 Name to Display Describe it all here ASC C3 Data
```

And the output display is the same whether I use the Encoding.UTF8 property or not. 
By "open like an xml" I mean, in addition to displaying the entire data in the file, also make the tags collapsible (the color and all that format-related stuff that (presumably) the browser (IE) puts in)

Comment: you need to create a xml formatted file for it to open like a xml file!

Comment: what does `open like an xml file` mean to you?

Comment: What if you dont specify encoding?

Comment: What does your XML file look like? I mean, have you checked your format and stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using flush? try putting it after fWrite.WriteLine

```
fWrite.Flush();
```

Comment: No, flushing the stream is not the problem since the data is all there in the file (as it shows when opened with notepad)

Comment: ohhh sorry about that :D

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, I found out the blunder I did - didn't used the opening element tags to close them as well (OOOOPs!).Than you all for your time (and apologize to have wasted it too). a C/C++ programmer on my first C# trial project, didn't want the complications of using the XML writer libs; and now am delighted that it still works doing the lib work simply by myself the C-style (contrary to my boss's insistence that it wont:)).  Will be careful next time I post